# Regex match between specified dates?

Tags: regex

I have the following date String format, taken from a large dataset:

```
Wed Oct 05 19:26:09 BST 2014
```

I need to extract the dates between `15th October 09:00` and `23rd October 11:00`

I currently have this regex: `(Oct\W\d\d\W\d\d\W\d\d\W\d\d)` which matches: `Oct 05 19:26:09`

How could I alter it to match the date and time ranges I have specified?

Comment: I can give you a regex.. but as @Maciej said.. it's not going to look pretty..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as [@Maciej Baranowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1846995/maciej-baranowski) said.. you shouldn't do this with RegExp. But just in case you must to, and there's no other alternative.. Here is the Regular expression for that condition:

EDIT: New answer based on OP comments. Only match dates in between 15th and 23rd of October and in between 9:00:00 and 11:00:00

```
#Oct\W(?:1[5-9]|2[0-3])\W(?:(?:0?9|10):\d{2}:\d{2}|11:00:00)#
```

You can see it working [here](https://xrg.es/#8ktn5b)

Comment: Thats great but the times have to be between 09:00 and 11:00

Comment: I thought you meant from 15th October 09:00 until 23rd October 11:00 or is it every day in that period between those hours? If you see the link I posted with the example you will see the results are in between those dates

Comment: yes in between those dates works fine. but also in between the times of 09:00 and 11:00

Comment: @Geem7n see the edited answer. That matches the criteria you described

Comment: That works great thanks.. although the format in which it is in dose not seem to work in Java? iv been testing my regexes on this site http://www.regexr.com/ and they seem to work in my code but yours does not... is it something to do with the hash symbols? => '#'.

Comment: fixed it with this => (Oct\W(?:1[5-9]|2[0-3])\W(?:(?:0?9|10):\d{2}:\d{2}|11:00:00)). Thanks

Comment: Yes @Geem7n sometimes you don't need the regex delimiter. I'm glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's a good approach to try to find a range of dates with single regex - it would surely be complicated and difficult to change and reuse in future. Wouldn't it be better to extract number of day in month to a variable in programming language you use? Dealing with comparisons would be trivial then. Of course it depends on the context of your problem